# Showing that following nested disks lead to sequence with one limit point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let's say I have a set $A \subset R^n$ and a limit point of the set $\vec x \in A$. Suppose I constructed a sequence of points in $A$ as follows. I take balls $B(\vec x, 1/k)$ for $k = 1, 2, 3\dots$ and I take a point in $A$ from each ball. Since $\vec x$ is a limit point of set, I know each ball will have a point of $A$.

This sequence constructed from nested balls will have $\vec x$ as limit point. I constructed this for a proof. But next exercise asks me to show that this constructed sequence only has $\vec x$ as limit point. I am having troubles with this one.

---

$\{1, 1/2, 1, 1/3, 1, 1/4, 1 \dots\}$ has two limit points as a sequence, $0$ and $1$. $\vec x$ is a limit point of a sequence if every ball around it always contains infinite number of points of the sequence. So, yeah the limit of that sequence is unique but maybe there is a limit point like the example I gave above, $0$ and $1$.

Comment: $\vec x$ will be a limit of your sequence, and limits of sequences in $R^n$ are unique if they exist.

Comment: The sequence with all those 1's is not constructed out of that nest of balls.

Comment: That example sequence below horizontal rule was added to make it clear that limit points and limits are different. See @José Carlos Santos's answer and comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** all the balls $B\left(\vec{x},\frac{1}{k}\right)$ are nested $B\left(\vec{x},\frac{1}{k+1}\right) \subset B\left(\vec{x},\frac{1}{k}\right)$ and diameter $\frac{2}{k}\rightarrow 0, k \to \infty $. According to [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem#Variant_in_complete_metric_spaces), $\vec{x}$ is the only vector $\in \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}B\left(\vec{x},\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$.

What you can do in your case, is to assume that there are two different limit points $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$. Using $d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) \leq d(\vec{x}, \vec{x_k}) + d(\vec{y}, \vec{x_k}) < \varepsilon $ will lead to a contradiction of the result above.

Comment: So, intuitively, if these limit points can be made as close as we want to each other, then we can show that nested balls' infinite intersection will contain them both? But what if these limit points are apart?

Comment: Well, that's the point, you have to find a contradiction that, due to the way $\{\vec{x_k}\}$ is constructed, $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ can not be apart. I didn't want to provide a full answer, but if you can't find that way, let me know, I will update my answer with complete details.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence converges to $\vec x$ and a sequence only has one limit.

Comment: I think limits and limits points are different for a sequence. Could you check my edit?

Comment: @meguli You are right: limits and limit points are different things. What I said is right nevertheless: $\vec x$ is *the* limit of your sequence and therefore it is the *only* limit point of the sequence. Yes, a sequence can have severel limit points, but when it converges (as in this case) it has only one.

Answer (score 0):

Your aim is to assume that there are two distinct limit points, and reach a contradiction.

Let $X, Y$ be these limits and let $d = d(X,Y) > 0$. Note that $\lceil \frac{1}{d} \rceil = n$ is a natural number.

Take the ball $B(X,\frac{1}{n})$ which does not contain $Y$, since $\frac{1}{n} < d$. This is your counter example.